# Mongodb: findOne by ObjectId inside an array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm having a hard time describing it.

Basically, here is the document I have stored in my database:

```js
_id: 5fcf596a27365fb14d938afa
vatid:"BE00000011"
name:"ACME Inc"
users: [  {
            _id: 5fcf596a27365fb14d938afb,
            id: 5fcf596a27365fb14d938af9,
            role:"admin"
          }
        ]
```

Id like to find the object that contains this id: 5fcf596a27365fb14d938af9 inside the users array.

What would the query look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the thing:

```
{"users.id" : "5fcf596a27365fb14d938af9"}
```

Comment: Yep! The only this is I have to add mongoose.Types.ObjectId(). Thank you sir!